# Find of symbolic links point to the same target

Tags: shell, files, symlink

How can I find all of the symbolic links in a directory, that point to the same target?

For example, here is a list files in a directory:

```
a.txt
b.txt
a -> target1
c -> target1
m -> target2
n -> target3
c.txt
z -> target1
```

I want to get a list of what linked to `target1`. So the expected output will be:

```
a
c
z
```

Comment: What would you want if there were recursive symlinks: `t -> z`? Would you want all four `a c z t` to be returned?

Comment: Yes. All of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following directory structure:

```
lrwxrwxrwx [...] a -> target1
lrwxrwxrwx [...] c -> target1
lrwxrwxrwx [...] m -> target2
lrwxrwxrwx [...] n -> target3
lrwxrwxrwx [...] t -> z
-rw-r--r-- [...] target1
-rw-r--r-- [...] target2
-rw-r--r-- [...] target3
lrwxrwxrwx [...] z -> target1
```

Use GNU `find` to find all files pointing to the same inode:

```
find -L . -samefile target1
```

- `-L` follows symlinks, even if you have recursive symlinks
- `-samefile` finds all files which point to the same inode as the given paramter `target1`

The output in the above directory would look like this:

```
./z
./a
./target1
./c
./t
```